# Выбор данных в зависимости от ид

Tags: postgresql

Как преобразовать запросы вида

```
SELECT 
  "F_Value"
FROM 
  "SC_Wonder"."T_Passport"
   WHERE    "ID_Product" = 2

SELECT 
  "F_Value"
FROM 
  "SC_Wonder"."T_Passport"
   WHERE    "ID_Product" = 3
```

в один, чтобы я конкретно знал, что первым числом будет значение с ид 2, вторым - с 3 и так далее?

**UPD**

- А если значения с ид 2 нет, как вернуть нуль?
- Я не могу гарантировать, что ид будут строго больше. Необходимо знать, что элемент с определенным ид придет строго определенным по счету либо придет null.

Comment:     SELECT "F_Value" FROM "SC_Wonder"."T_Passport" WHERE "ID_Product" IN (2,3) ORDER BY ID_Product;

Comment: ну вообще отсортировать в том же порядке проще на стороне приложения, в SQL-запросе это проблематично сделать, а сам SQL такой, как @ua6xh выше предложил, только ORDER BY в таком случае не нужен